# Why changing start method to 'spawn' from 'fork' in Python multiprocessing does not allow me run my job anymore?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, spawn

I am able to run a background function using `multiprocessing.Process` with the start method `fork`. For some reason, I need this child process to start a new environment when running. So I set the start method to `spawn` via `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` and run the job via `job.start()` I get the following error:

```
Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed
```

However, I do not use pickle for anything within the function that I am calling. What could I be doing wrong? Is there a general rule of thumb that I should have followed when running processes in `spawn` mode?

FYI: I am on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to transport data between processes.  In 'spawn' mode this is the only way that any data gets to a process; 'fork' at least allows pre-generated data to be shared without being pickled.  I'm guessing you're using some sort of dynamically-defined class, which presents difficulties with pickling.

Comment: Stick to basic types in the `Process` class and whatever function / parameters it runs. Have that function call a different function that does all of its own imports of the fancy stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a general rule of thumb...

Yes. You ran into this documented restriction:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

> There are a few extra restriction which don’t apply to the fork start method.
>
> More picklability
>
> Ensure that all arguments to Process.**init**() are picklable. Also, if you subclass Process then make sure that instances will be picklable when the Process.start method is called.

You are running on ubuntu, so `fork` is probably the right answer. If there is a requirement you need to address which `fork` is incompatible with, then you will want to clearly document the details as the first part of choosing an improved solution.